# Pandas assigning value to variable with two column filters from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframne:

```
df
                Name    Jan Feb Mar
Description             
New             A       34  32  54
Old             B       65  98  05
Retired         C       96  26  43
```

Description is an index column.

I am trying to assign a value to variable as follows:

```py
variable = df[(df['Description']=='Retired') & (df['Name']=='C')]["Jan"]
```

But i am getting an error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with compare index - output is `Series` - with one or more values:

```
variable = df.loc[(df.index=='Retired') & (df['Name']=='C'), "Jan"]
print (variable)
Description
Retired    96
Name: Jan, dtype: int64
```

If need select first and always exist at least one value use:

```
print (variable.iat[0])
96
```

But if possible no match, then is returned empty Series and cannot select like above, then is possible use `next-iter` trick with possible set default value if empty Series:

```
variable = df.loc[(df.index=='Retired') & (df['Name']=='another'), "Jan"]
print (variable)
Series([], Name: Jan, dtype: int64)

print (next(iter(variable), 'no match'))
no match
```

Another better solution is add `Name` to index for `MultiIndex` and then select by `tuple` if need scalar output:

```
df = df.set_index('Name', append=True)

variable = df.loc[('Retired','C'), "Jan"]
print (variable)
96
```

Comment: Since i am going to use this variable to further code, when i enter variable, it should show only 96, nothing else. Is it possible to use df.loc and df.at in a single line of code? ```no_days = df.loc[df.index,'Name'].at['Jan']
```. I am not able to use this since i have to filter the description column also.

Comment: @RSM - second solution with `df = df.set_index('Name', append=True)

variable = df.loc[('Retired','C'), "Jan"]
print (variable)` is not possible use?

Comment: Sorry @jezreal, i still do not get a single number i get same output as ```Description  Name
Retired C      96
Name: Jan, dtype: float64```

Comment: @RSM - In last paragraph solution?