# Assign a filtered value with pandas to a python variable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas to filter results from a column in the worksheet, and I need to assign some values to variables, but I can't

My code snippet below makes the filter

```
variable = clientes.loc[(clientes['Data']=='08/02/2023')]
print(variable)
```

Below the result

```
 Nome do paciente        Data Horário  Email     Telefone Tipo de agendamento           Situação Status Financeiro Observação
34          Teste 1  08/02/2023   10h00    NaN          NaN                 NaN  Paciente agendado          Não pago        NaN
35          Teste 2  08/02/2023   13h30    NaN          NaN                 NaN  Paciente agendado          Não pago        NaN
36          Teste 3  08/02/2023   15h00    NaN   55544454.0    Consulta Simples  Paciente agendado          Não pago        NaN
37          Teste 4  08/02/2023   18h00    NaN  555445454.0    Consulta Simples  Paciente agendado          Não pago        NaN
38          Teste 5  08/02/2023   20h00    NaN          NaN                 NaN  Paciente agendado          Não pago        NaN
```

Below are the values I need to assign to a variable. ideally a list

```
   Nome do paciente      Data      Horário
    Teste 1            08/02/2023   10h00
    Teste 2            08/02/2024   13h30
    Teste 3            08/02/2025   15h00
    Teste 4            08/02/2026   18h00
    Teste 5            08/02/2027   20h00
```

I checked the solution from the link below, but I couldn't adapt it to my code

[Pandas assigning value to variable with two column filters from dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61745393/pandas-assigning-value-to-variable-with-two-column-filters-from-dataframe)

Comment: Hello @Brandalize. Please provide the solutions you have tried so far, or other SO (Stack Overflow) solutions you may have looked at but didn't work.

Comment: Hello @LoukasPap. I just updated the question by inserting what I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not specifying the columns which you need. Try the below code.

```
variable = clientes.loc[(clientes['Data']=='08/02/2023')][['Nome do paciente',       'Data', 'Horário']]

print(variable)

final_list = []

[final_list.extend(i) for in variable.values.tolist()]

print(final_list)
```

final_list will give you the list like below

['Teste 1', '08/02/2023', '10h00', 'Teste 2', '08/02/2024', '13h30'...................]

Comment: This brought me just the columns I wanted. But I still need to assign these values to variables.

Comment: Each column to a variable or each row or each value?

Comment: Each column is a list variable. Or better yet, a single list variable with all values being index separated by lines